# Reading OTP from users Mobile automatically in meteor + Cordova

Tags: cordova, meteor, one-time-password

I am currently working on an app where after the user enters the phone no during registration process, an auto-generated OTP is sent to his/her mobile. In the very next page he/she needs to put the OTP and hit next so that he/she can set the password. Now I want to automate the process, like when OTP comes my app should be able to detect and autofill the OTP input box.

Using Meteor 1.3.3
Cordova for generating mobile apps

Comment: What is the method of delivery for the one-time password? If it's Android your app can monitor SMS, but not on iOS.  You could send a custom URL scheme that is registered to your app, so that when you click the URL it passes the OTP to your app.  e.g. myappregister://thisismypassword

Comment: I am sending the message via msg91 API.